# can i get any alternative for pywin32?

Tags: python, macos, pywin32

can i get any alternative for pywin32 for macos because it doesn't seems to work in macos.

i tried installing it in my macbook through terminal but it showed something like

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

Answer (score 1):

`pywin32` is the extension that provides access to Windows APIs, which are available only on Windows.

It's useful only if you are executing the app on a Windows host. If you run it on macOS, there are no Windows APIs available there, thus your error about a version mismatch.

So, you can't have an alternative for `pywin32` on macOS, because `pywin32` is not supposed to be used under this platform, you may be trying to run an app that is Windows-specific.